# Gray screen and unsuable GNOME Shell after wake from hibernate in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, login, dell, gnome-shell, hibernate

This only started recently. But whenever I close my laptop and open it again, I get a blank gray screen. The top bar that is normally populated with a handful of GNOME shell extensions is vastly simplified (extensions aren't there), and the battery power dropdown doesn't give the option to restart the computer. After about 30 seconds or so, the computer will fall asleep. I have to hit my power button to manually induce a sleep before that happens. Then, I have to wake up my computer, again with the power button. But then, my login page is also gray (was previously orange with Bionic Beaver theme), but there's a box for me to type my password in and I can login. Finally, once I've logged in from this gray screen situation, my top bar is always messed up, so I have to restart the GNOME shell to get it back to normal.

Alternatively, sometimes when opening my laptop back up, my proper desktop background shows, but the proper GNOME Shell (top bar) and the reduced one from the gray screen are both present, and everything flickers, making the computer unusable. I have to force restart.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening? I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with on-chip Intel HD graphics and the Linux 4.15.0-1030-oem kernel. I do have a PCIe NVMe SED SSD (acronym time), as other people with somewhat similar problems seem to be wondering about. It's very annoying to have to hack through this every time I close my laptop screen. :(

I found these logs in /var/log/syslog that occurred when I closed my laptop and re-opened it:

```
Jan 20 23:16:20 <my-comp> gnome-shell[1844]: Failed to read EDID from 'eDP-1': No such file or directory
Jan 20 23:16:20 <my-comp> gnome-shell[1844]: message repeated 2 times: [ Failed to read EDID from 'eDP-1': No such file or directory]
Jan 20 23:16:20 <my-comp> gsd-color[1943]: failed to set screen _ICC_PROFILE: Failed to open file “/home/<my-home>/.local/share/icc/edid-6659083584814522f0fa1e7e1ebd8650.icc”: Permission denied
Jan 20 23:16:20 <my-comp> gnome-shell[2540]: Object St.BoxLayout (0x55969cf07dd0), has been already deallocated - impossible to access it. This might be caused by the object having been destroyed from C code usin
g something such as destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs
...
Jan 20 23:16:07 <my-comp> gnome-shell[2540]: Object Shell.GenericContainer (0x55969dfd1310), has been already finalized. Impossible to set any property to it.
Jan 20 23:16:07 <my-comp> gnome-shell[2540]: Object Shell.GenericContainer (0x55969dfd1310), has been already deallocated - impossible to access it. This might be caused by the object having been destroyed from C
 code using something such as destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs
```